# Error: 'NA' does not exist in current working directory

Tags: html, r

Estoy trabajando con R e intentando hacer web scraping con una página web. La descarga incluye datos de varios enlaces que con un paste debería estar ya solucionado ya que solo va cambiando el número de página, hice esto para ello:

```
ids <- 2:5
files <- paste0("https://www.infocif.es/ranking/ventas-empresas/espana?pagina=",ids)
```

Empieza en 2 porque la primera página tiene una url distinta a las demás y entiendo que esto no debería fallar.

Después cree un bucle que yo creo que también debería funcionar pero aquí es donde viene el error:

```
for (i in files){
  col_page <- read_html(files[i])
  col_table <- col_page %>% html_nodes("table#tablaranking") %>% html_table()
}
```

Al ejecutar el bucle me salta el error de los NA y la verdad que no se por donde tirar para solucionarlo.

Si intento descargar de una página concreta me lo hace sin ningún problema así que entiendo que el problema está en el bucle lógicamente.

He intentado usar **read_xml** por si era eso pero nada.

Si alguien sabe de que va este error porque he visto varia info por foros pero nada me soluciona el problema.

Gracias!!

PD: Ejecutando el código el error ya salta en la primera línea del bucle, en la función read_html

Comment: Bienvenido Pablo, nos alegra que te sumes a stackoverflow. Para que tus preguntas sean mejor recibidas te sugiero revisar esta pagina donde muestran [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/asking). También puedes realizar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que aprendas un poco más de como funciona la pagina y de paso ganar tur primeras medallas.

Comment: Pablo estuve revisando la pagina y lo que sucede es que el contenido de la misma es dinámico. Y por lo que deduzco de tu código estas utilizando el paquete rvest para el scrap, es correcto? Si estoy en lo correcto te menciono que rvest no puede ser utilizado en paginas con contenido dinámico y te recomiendo revises el paquete Rselenium o en su defecto uses selenium desde python que a mi me ha resultado más practico.

Comment: Así es Rolando, estoy con el paquete rvest. Genial muchas gracias, echaré un vistazo a los dos paquetes que me has dicho a ver si con eso puedo tirar

Answer (score 0):

En este caso me parece que tu problema esta en el indice que estas usando.

Al hacer `i in files` ya estas iterando sobre el vector y el valor que guarda `i` es la dirección y no el indice. Por lo que no debes usar `files[i]` si no que solamente `i`.

Por lo tanto el código del for debería ser:

```
for (i in files){
  col_page <- read_html(i)
  col_table <- col_page %>% html_nodes("table#tablaranking") %>% html_table()
}
```